# Knockout.js: Cannot bind to custom @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using a selector to build a custom @Html.EditorFor (called @Html.FullFieldEditor). It determines the type of input to generate (textbox, drop down, radio buttons, check boxes, etc.). I have been trying to hook it into one for a radio button list, thusly:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.MyModel.MyRadioButton, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data_bind", "myRadioButton" } })
```

or like this:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.MyModel.MyRadioButton, new { data_bind = "checked: myRadioButton" })
```

But with no luck.

I was trying to fix my `selector.cshtml` code but only wound up making a horrible mess.  Here is the code that has worked for me BEFORE I was trying to implement `knockout.js`:

```
@{
var supportsMany = typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType);
var selectorModel = (Selector)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["SelectorModelMetadata"];
var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("");
var validationClass = ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(fieldName) ? "" : "input-validation-error";


// Loop through the items and make sure they are Selected if the value has been posted
if(Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in selectorModel.Items)
    {
        if (supportsMany)
        {
            var modelStateValue = GetModelStateValue<string[]>(Html, fieldName) ?? ((IEnumerable)Model).OfType<object>().Select(m => m.ToString());
            item.Selected = modelStateValue.Contains(item.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var modelStateValue = GetModelStateValue<string>(Html, fieldName);
            if (modelStateValue != null)
            {
                item.Selected = modelStateValue.Equals(item.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
            else
            {
                Type modelType = Model.GetType();
                if (modelType.IsEnum)
                {
                    item.Selected = item.Value == Model.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
@functions
{
    public MvcHtmlString BuildInput(string fieldName, 
    SelectListItem item, string inputType, object htmlAttributes) 
    // UPDATE: Trying to do it above
    {
    var id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.Value);
    var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrapper.AddCssClass("selector-item");

    var input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.MergeAttribute("type", inputType);
    input.MergeAttribute("name", fieldName);
    input.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
    input.MergeAttribute("id", id);

    input.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)); 
    // UPDATE: and trying above, but see below in the 
    // @foreach...@BuildInput section

    input.MergeAttributes(Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(fieldName, ViewData.ModelMetadata));

    if(item.Selected)
        input.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

    wrapper.InnerHtml += input.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);


    var label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.MergeAttribute("for", id);
    label.InnerHtml = item.Text;
    wrapper.InnerHtml += label;

    return new MvcHtmlString(wrapper.ToString());
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the raw value from model state
/// </summary>
public static T GetModelStateValue<T>(HtmlHelper helper, string key)
{
    ModelState modelState;
    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out modelState) && modelState.Value != null)
        return (T)modelState.Value.ConvertTo(typeof(T), null);
    return default(T);
}
}
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly)
{
var readonlyText = selectorModel.Items.Where(i => i.Selected).ToDelimitedString(i => i.Text);
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readonlyText))
{
    readonlyText = selectorModel.OptionLabel ?? "Not Set";
}

@readonlyText

foreach (var item in selectorModel.Items.Where(i => i.Selected))
{
@Html.Hidden(fieldName, item.Value)
}
}
else
{
if (selectorModel.AllowMultipleSelection)
{
    if (selectorModel.Items.Count() < selectorModel.BulkSelectionThreshold)
    {
<div class="@validationClass">
    @foreach (var item in selectorModel.Items)
            {
        @BuildInput(fieldName, item, "checkbox") // throwing error here if I leave this as is (needs 4 arguments)
        //But if I do this:
        //@BuildInput(fieldName, item, "checkbox", htmlAttributes) // I get does not exit in current context

            }
</div>
    }
    else
    {
@Html.ListBox("", selectorModel.Items)
    }
}
else if (selectorModel.Items.Count() < selectorModel.BulkSelectionThreshold)
{
<div class="@validationClass">
    @*@if (selectorModel.OptionLabel != null)
        {
        @BuildInput(fieldName, new SelectListItem { Text = selectorModel.OptionLabel, Value = "" }, "radio")
        }*@
    @foreach (var item in selectorModel.Items)
        {
        @BuildInput(fieldName, item, "radio")//same here
        }
</div>
}
else
{
@Html.DropDownList("", selectorModel.Items, selectorModel.OptionLabel)
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I am trying to minimize existing `JS` code (over 1500 lines) to show/hide with KO (which just seems to be able to cut down the code considerably). I know I've got choices (`visible`, `if`, etc.) with KO, but assuming what I wanted to accomplish with KO was doable I could go with `visible`. In any event, getting past the binding hurdle prevents me from getting that far.

Here is an example of some code I am using to show/hide with plain `JS`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='MyModel.MyRadioButton']").click(function () {
        var radio_value = $(this).val();
        if (radio_value == '1') {
            $("#MyRadioButton_1").show();
            $("#MyRadioButton_2").hide();
            $("#MyRadioButton_3").hide();
        }
        else if (radio_value == '2') {
            $("#MyRadioButton_1").show();
            $("#MyRadioButton_2").hide();
            $("#MyRadioButton_3").hide();
        }
        else if (radio_value == '3') {
            $("#MyRadioButton_1").show();
            $("#MyRadioButton_2").hide();
            $("#MyRadioButton_3").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#MyRadioButton_1").hide();
    $("#MyRadioButton_2").hide();
    $("#MyRadioButton_3").hide();
});
```

I figured KO could minimize the above. Again, I'm looking at 20-30 inputs, most with more than 3 choices (a few have 10 choices in a Drop Down). This is getting hard to maintain at 1500 lines and growing.

And then in my `view` I've got this going on:

```
<div id="MyRadioButton_1">
    @Helpers.StartingCost(MyModel.Choice1, "1")
</div>
<div id="MyRadioButton_2">
    @Helpers.StartingCost(MyModel.Choice2, "2")
</div>
<div id="MyRadioButton_3">
    @Helpers.StartingCost(MyModel.Choice2, "2")
</div>
```

The `view` code above will change slightly with KO, but again its the `JS` I am trying to cut down on.

**EDIT 2**
This is part of the code for `FullFieldEditor`. Some parts are left out for brevity (such as code for `RequiredFor`, `ToolTipFor` and `SpacerFor`).

```
public static MvcHtmlString FullFieldEditor<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return FullFieldEditor(html, expression, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString FullFieldEditor<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

        if (!metadata.ShowForEdit)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        if (metadata.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            return html.EditorFor(expression);
        }

        var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
        wrapper.AddCssClass("field-wrapper");
        var table = new TagBuilder("table");
        table.Attributes["border"] = "0";
        table.Attributes["width"] = "100%";//added this to even out table columns
        var tbody = new TagBuilder("tbody");
        var tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
        var td1 = new TagBuilder("td");
        td1.Attributes["width"] = "40%";
        td1.Attributes["valign"] = "top";
        var label = new TagBuilder("div");
        label.AddCssClass("field-label");
        label.AddCssClass("mylabelstyle");
        label.InnerHtml += html.MyLabelFor(expression);
        td1.InnerHtml = label.ToString();
        var td2 = new TagBuilder("td");
        td2.Attributes["width"] = "50%";
        td2.Attributes["valign"] = "top";
        var input = new TagBuilder("div");
        input.AddCssClass("field-input");

        input.InnerHtml += html.EditorFor(expression);
        td2.InnerHtml = input.ToString();
        var td3 = new TagBuilder("td");
        td3.Attributes["width"] = "5%";
        td3.Attributes["valign"] = "top";
        if (metadata.IsRequired && !metadata.IsReadOnly)
        {
            td3.InnerHtml += html.RequiredFor(expression);
        }
        var td4 = new TagBuilder("td");
        td4.Attributes["width"] = "5%";
        td4.Attributes["valign"] = "middle";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.Description))
        {
            td4.InnerHtml += html.TooltipFor(expression);
        }
        else td4.InnerHtml += html.SpacerFor(expression);
        td4.InnerHtml += html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
        tr.InnerHtml = td1.ToString() + td2.ToString() + td3.ToString() + td4.ToString();
        tbody.InnerHtml = tr.ToString();
        table.InnerHtml = tbody.ToString();
        wrapper.InnerHtml = table.ToString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(wrapper + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**
The options are not working. Option 1 will not even show `data-bind` in the `<input>`. Option 2 will not work since it's just checking if the field is required (the code just shows a "required" image if it is).

When I tried your first suggestion before your **"UPDATE2"** (`input.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));`), this was the output:

```
<div class="field-input" data_bind="checked: MyRadioButton">
    <div class="">
        <div class="selector-item">
            <input id="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1" name="MyModel.MyRadioButton" type="radio" value="Choice1">
            <label for="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1">I am thinking about Choice 1.</label>
        </div>
        <!--Just showing one radio button for brevity-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I merged the attribute with the `input` part of `TagBuilder`, which is outputting the `field-input` `<div>`, that is where it's being placed (which is logical). Notice that it should be `data-bind` but is showing as `data_bind` in the `field-input` class. This is how I have the `FullFieldEditor`:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.MyModel.MyRadioButton, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data_bind", "myRadioButton" } })
```

What it should be showing up as is this, I think:

```
<div class="field-input">
    <div class="">
        <div class="selector-item">
            <!-- "data-bind" should be showing up in the following INPUT, correct?-->
            <input data-bind="checked: MyRadioButton" id="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1" name="MyModel.MyRadioButton" type="radio" value="Choice1">
            <label for="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1">I am thinking about Choice 1.</label>
        </div>
        <!--Just showing one radio button for brevity-->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I suspect is that I have to get that `htmlAttributes` into the `Selector.cshtml` above, and not in the `HtmlFormHelper.cs` file.  The `Selector.cshtml` is what is making the determination between showing, for example, a drop down list, a radio button list or a checkbox list (among others). The `Selector.cshtml` is a template in the `Shared\EditorTemplates` folder.

For background: I have dozens of forms representing hundreds of inputs over dozens of pages (or wizards). I am using the `@Html.FullFieldEditor` because it was easier to maintain than having spaghetti code for each type of input (drop down, checkbox, radio buttons, etc.).

**UPDATE 4**
Still not working.

I tried this in the `Selector.cshtml` (its the `BuildInput` function)code and was able to get "data-bind" into the `<input>` tag for each radio button in the list:

```
input.MergeAttribute("data-bind", htmlAttributes);
```

and then I did this lower down in the same file:

```
@foreach (var item in selectorModel.Items)
    {
        @BuildInput(fieldName, item, "radio", "test")
    }
```

and my HTML output is this:

```
<div class="selector-item">
    <input data-bind="test" id="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1" name="MyModel.MyRadioButton" type="radio" value="Choice1">
    <label for="MyModel_MyRadioButton_Choice1">Choice 1</label>
</div>
```

**Which is what is leading me to believe it's the `Selector.cshtml` file, not the `HtmlFormHelper.cs` file.**

I am going to open up the bounty to everyone 50+.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @JasonMore No. Not sure if I am on the right track looking at my `Selector.cshmtl` rather than the `HtmlFormHelper.cs`. If you look at my "Update 4" I was able to put a string in the right place. Just a matter of figuring out how to pass the data-bind. I'm not a programmer, so the more nuanced stuff escapes me.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the issue you are having now, since you said you have the data bind in the right spot.

Comment: @JasonMore But all I passed was a simple string. I made the `htmlAttributes` that I noted in my "Update 4" a `string` instead of an `object` like you had suggested earlier on. If I do `object` instead when I do the `@foreach . . . { @BuildInput(fieldName, item, "radio", htmlAttributes) }` I get a "does not exist in the current context" for the `htmlAttributes` part. If I leave it out it throws an error because it's expecting 4 parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE3**

First good call on the underscore bit, I totally forgot about that. Your bit of code looks almost right, but should actually be this:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.MyModel.MyRadioButton, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data_bind", "checked:myRadioButton" } })
```

So since you are dynamically selecting between checkbox and text, you'll have to do a couple of things. If its a checkbox, you'll have to use the code above. If its a textbox, you'll have to use:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.MyModel.MyTextBox, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data_bind", "value:MyTextBox" } })
```

**UPDATE2**

So I updated your code where I ***think*** the data-bind belongs in your html (marked option1 and option2). What would be helpful is if you gave me a snippet of the html being generated, along with where you need the data bind.

```
public static MvcHtmlString FullFieldEditor<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
{
    return FullFieldEditor(html, expression, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString FullFieldEditor<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

    if (!metadata.ShowForEdit)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    if (metadata.HideSurroundingHtml)
    {
        return html.EditorFor(expression);
    }

    var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrapper.AddCssClass("field-wrapper");

    var table = new TagBuilder("table");
    table.Attributes["border"] = "0";

    //added this to even out table columns
    table.Attributes["width"] = "100%";

    var tbody = new TagBuilder("tbody");

    var td1 = new TagBuilder("td");
    td1.Attributes["width"] = "40%";
    td1.Attributes["valign"] = "top";

    var label = new TagBuilder("div");
    label.AddCssClass("field-label");
    label.AddCssClass("mylabelstyle");
    label.InnerHtml += html.MyLabelFor(expression);

    td1.InnerHtml = label.ToString();

    var td2 = new TagBuilder("td");
    td2.Attributes["width"] = "50%";
    td2.Attributes["valign"] = "top";

    var input = new TagBuilder("div");
    input.AddCssClass("field-input");

    // option1
    input.InnerHtml += html.EditorFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    td2.InnerHtml = input.ToString();

    var td3 = new TagBuilder("td");
    td3.Attributes["width"] = "5%";
    td3.Attributes["valign"] = "top";

    if (metadata.IsRequired && !metadata.IsReadOnly)
    {
        // option2
        td3.InnerHtml += html.RequiredFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }

    var td4 = new TagBuilder("td");
    td4.Attributes["width"] = "5%";
    td4.Attributes["valign"] = "middle";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.Description))
    {
        td4.InnerHtml += html.TooltipFor(expression);
    }
    else
    {
        td4.InnerHtml += html.SpacerFor(expression);
    }

    td4.InnerHtml += html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);

    var tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
    tr.InnerHtml = td1.ToString() + td2.ToString() + td3.ToString() + td4.ToString();

    tbody.InnerHtml = tr.ToString();
    table.InnerHtml = tbody.ToString();
    wrapper.InnerHtml = table.ToString();

    return new MvcHtmlString(wrapper + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**UPDATE**

While I still believe below is the "correct" answer, here is what your tagbuilder is missing so you can pass custom attributes along:

```
input.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
```

**Original Answer**

I have a feeling that what is going to happen by trying to mix razor and knockout, is the razor stuff will render, then when knockout is attached, the values in the knockout viewmodel are going to override whatever was in the razor view.

Here is my suggestion if you are trying to refactor to knockout:

1. Create an html only view (no razor).
2. Add your knockout bindings to it.
3. Pass your model data to knockout in the form of a json object using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). You can do this in a variety of ways, but the easiest being simply stuffing the data on the view inside of a `<script>` tag that your javascript can find.
4. Use [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to load the json object into the viewmodel.

Comment: While I see your point, right now I am concerned with manipulating user input on the page. I am not saving it, but rather passing it along in a wizard to a final "Confirm" page. I am really wanting to minimize the JS I am using to accomplish showing/hiding `<div>` elements. I thought KO could minimize lines. Right now I have a separate `.js` file that has 1500 lines of code to show/hide. SEE ABOVE EDIT for an example.

Comment: Yep, knockout will be perfect in this situation. The issue is you need to start seperating your view logic into multiple viewmodels, then re-using code using foreach and templating. Have you gone through  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ ? It will help you a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's where I started out. I just cannot hook it up into my custom `EditorFor`.

Comment: Unfortunately that works but only to put the `"data-bind"` in the `field-input` `<div>`, not in the `<input>` where it needs to be. I was trying to use your code in the `TagBuilder` located in my `Selector.cshtml` (the first large block of code I posted in my question), but to no avail. I am going to mark that code up with what I tried (just give me a few minutes).

Comment: Not on point with my updates (see "UPDATE" in the first large code block). Your suggestion works in the `.cs` file but puts `data-bind` in the wrong place. I couldn't get your suggestion to work in the `Selector.cshtml` file. I'll give you 50+ bounty if we can get it to work (sorry if I'm not on consistently). Also +1 for the extended effort.

Comment: Sure. Which field are you expecting the data-bind to show up on?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have understood your difficulty. But if your difficulty is where and how to place the data-bind depending of the input fields you used to render your property
give a look to the [ClientBlocks](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Blocks) features of the [Mvc Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/). It computes most of the binding automatically, by precompiling templates(that is razor helpers or PartialViews that display pieces of the page), or the full view.
That is you can just write: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myProperty) and an adequate data-bind between the textbox and the myProperty of your client side ViewModel will be created, and so on with selects, radios etc. You can also to avoid using helper and just give your fileds "adequate names" and the binding is automatically computed. Moreover you can decide wichh part of the Server Side ViewModel to transfer to the client...your client side ViewmOdel will be transferred back inside the Server Side ViewModel automatically on post.

Comment: This is not really helpful. I've got one paradigm (KO) to contend with on top of my own paradigm and your solution is to check out a third paradigm?

Comment: It is not a 3d paradigm it is a way to generate automatically the "adequate" ko data-bind attribute based on a name convention. This way it should be easier to transform something working without ko into something working with ko without toom many modification in the Partial View you already built. On the other side you should use ko templates plus the "with" and "if" ko templates operators to simplify your js. Clearly, maybe it is not worth for you to add further tools to your solution, if thir use is limited just to that EditorFor